# How to use ChakraUI extended fonts

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

Hello I have question can I have 2 different fonts for Heading like you know you define
`<Heading fontFamily={???}></Heading>` and set font family inside it. I do not want to have one font family for heading.

```
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const theme = extendTheme({
  fonts: {
    heading: "Dancing Script",
  },
});

export default theme;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can write `<Heading fontFamily="myFont1"></Heading>` and `<Heading fontFamily="myFont2">Some Text</Heading>` if you declare these two fonts in your extended theme:

```js
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import "@fontsource/dancing-script";

const theme = extendTheme({
  fonts: {
    myFont1: "Dancing Script",
    myFont2: "Times New Roman",
  },
});

export default theme;
```

Also, notice that I didn't have to import any external library for Times New Roman (because it's likely to already be installed on you users' computer) but I had to import `@fontsource/dancing-script` because it's not a standard font. (Remember to install it with `npm install --save @fontsource/dancing-script` before you use it).

You can probably find any fonts you need on [FontSource](https://fontsource.org/fonts), and for more information (and alternative solutions) there is the Chakra UI [documentation on fonts](https://chakra-ui.com/guides/recipes/using-fonts).

Answer (score 0):

To add to Giorgio's answer, if you want to have as much code as possible in the theme definition, you can even declare the font for all variations of headers.

```
<Heading>h1 text</Heading>
<Heading as="h2">h2 text</Heading>
```

and then configure your theme like this:

```
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import "@fontsource/dancing-script";

const theme = extendTheme({
  fonts: {
    heading: "Dancing Script",
    subHeading: "Times New Roman",
  },
  textStyles: {
    h2: {
      'font-family': 'var(--chakra-fonts-subHeading)',
    },
  }
});

export default theme;
```

You'll notice that unfortunately, I had to use `'font-family'` instead of `fontFamily` (it seems to be an existing bug, same for `font-weight`)  and reference the variable this way: `var(--chakra-fonts-subHeading)`